# Is there an existing function to add docstrings, relevant to the current major mode?

Tags: major-mode, doc-strings

In emacs is there a function that I can invoke to add a docstring template based on the current major mode?

eg:

If I'm working on javascript, insert a javascript docstring template "here", like:

`/**
 * Docstring
 * 
 */`

If I'm working on python, insert a python docstring template "here", like:

`"""Docstring"""`

Comment: Looks like a job for `auto-insert`.